# Bind input element to Observable in Angular

Tags: html, angular, rxjs

I'm missing something basic. But all similar posts that i found contained solutions with @Input and objects i haven't found any with a simple variable.

So i have a component with a list of posts and a input.

so here is my HTML:

```
<input placeholder="Enter value that title or body should conain" [(ngModel)]="filterString$" />
```

And here is my Typescript:

```
filterString$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('').asObservable();

this.filterString$.subscribe((filterString) => {
   this.filterPosts(filterString);
});
```

The problem is that it fires only once ( ofc because i have a problem exactly in HTML binding ). and input displays: [object Object]

What is incorrect in my binding?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to two-way bind my own RxJS Subject to an \[(ngModel)\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662155/how-to-two-way-bind-my-own-rxjs-subject-to-an-ngmodel)

Your `filterString$` needs to be a Subject since you would also need to push new values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extending Angular 2 ngModel directive to use observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38844835/extending-angular-2-ngmodel-directive-to-use-observables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can bind an observable to ngModel input.
Anyway you can do it much simpler, for example like this:

```html
<input (ngModelChange)="filterPosts($event)" [(ngModel)]="filterString" />
```

Comment: yup, overcomplicated the scenario myself... How i didn't come up with this

Comment: You should do `[ngModel]="filterString"`, it works the way you did it but it's bad practice as there will be two chefs in the kitchen. The () in [(ngModel)] is an alias for (ngModelChange).